# cant store the file using storeAs in laravel

Tags: laravel, file-upload

[image]
[image]

iam using a laravel site and in my file i have a directory in path
/var/www/site/admin.site.com/public/storage/salescall
i need to upload a file to this salescall folder i have used the following code.

```
     $filenameWithExt = $request->file('sales_call')->getClientOriginalName();
     $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
     $extension = $request->file('sales_call')->getClientOriginalExtension();
     $filenameToStore = $filename . '-' . time() . '.' . $extension;

     $request->file('sales_call')
    ->storeAs('', $filenameToStore, 'sales');
```

and my filesystems.php is as follows

'disks' => [

```
    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET'),
        'region' => env('AWS_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
    ],
    'sales' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path('salescall'),
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
],
```

file is not uploaded to folder.please help me to solve this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this

```
'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
    'visibility' => 'public',
    'permissions' => [
        'file' => [
            'public' => 0664,
            'private' => 0600,
        ],
        'dir' => [
            'public' => 0775,
            'private' => 0700,
        ],
    ],
],

$request->file('sales_call')-> storeAs('salescall/',$filenameToStore);
```

Comment: i have chaged to 'local' => to 'root' => storage_path('salescall'), and used $request->file('sales_call')-> storeAs('salescall/',$filenameToStore); but nothing get uploaded to folder

Comment: @user2830078 I updated my answer. Please check again

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this:

```
$request->file('sales_call')-> storeAs('salescall/',$filenameToStore);
```

FOR BETTER UNDERSTANDING, SEE BELOW

> The configuration of your filesystem seems to be incorrect.
> Use the below sample as a guide and I hope it helps you.

If you use this code, it will upload your file in storage/app folder

`Storage::disk('local')->put('file.txt', 'Contents');`

Now, if you need to change the directory and store into the storage folder directly, you need to change something in the filesystems.php file.

Go to config/filesystems.php file and change the following code-

```
'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],
```

Here, this line of code 'root' => storage_path('app'), responsible to define where to store. You just adjust according to your demands.

Alternatively, In your controller, You could do something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class UserAvatarController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle the incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        
        $request->validate([
            'avatar'=> ['required','max:200'] 
        ]);

        $user = User::findOrFail(auth()->user()->id);

        // Handle file Upload
        if($request->hasFile('avatar')){

            //Storage::delete('/public/avatars/'.$user->avatar);

            // Get filename with the extension
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('avatar')->getClientOriginalName();
            //Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            // Get just ext
            $extension = $request->file('avatar')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // Filename to store
            $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            // Upload Image
            $path = $request->file('avatar')->storeAs('public/avatars',$fileNameToStore);

       $user->avatar = $fileNameToStore ;

            $user->save(); 
        }

       
       
        
        return $user;
    }
}
```

But in your own case, I believe:

1. In your config, set the root key to storage_path('salescall')
2. Yours should be $path = $request->file('sales_call')->storeAs('public/salescall',$fileNameToStore);

Just let me know if this works.. Cheers!

Comment: i have chaged to   'local' => to 'root' => storage_path('salescall'),
and used $request->file('sales_call')->storeAs('public/salescall',$fileNameToStore); but nothing get uploaded to folder

Comment: Is the name of the file in the request body sales_call?

Comment: Please do a Screenshot of the necessary files also.

Comment: yes the file file name is sales_call. i have attached the screenshots also